# Function that yields different result depending on the random choice of virtual agent

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to define a function that yields a different result depending on the random choice of a virtual partner. The game is implemented via submission.
I have created an array and then a random choice. Next I am trying to implement an if statement with several conditions. But it doesn't returns the alert.
Thanks for your comments.

```html
<h1>What is your choice?</h1><br>
<form id="d1">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Cooperate"> Cooperate
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Betray"> Betray
</form>
<button onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
<script>
  function submitAnswer() {
    var selected = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value;
    var myArray = ['Cooperate', 'Betray'];
    var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
    if (selected === "Cooperate" || rand === "Cooperate") {
      alert("2");
    } else if (selected === "Betray" || rand === "Cooperate") {
      alert("3");
    } else if (selected === "Cooperate" || rand === "Betray") {
      alert("0");
    } else if (selected === "Betray" || rand === "Betray") {
      alert("1");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: your form is autosubmitting.

Comment: You also have a lot of syntax errors. If statements are written like `if(condition || condition)` not like `if(condition) || (condition)`

Comment: Hi @Daniel A. White , thank you for your reply. Sorry I am new in js. What do you mean by autosubmitting?

Comment: @messerbill that's actually incorrect regarding javascript. `if(condition) || (condition)` will give you an error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some rogue brackets. In Javascript that whole conditional clause must be surrounded by brackets. Also to prevent auto submitting, set the type of the button to "button". Try this:

```html
<h1>What is your choice?</h1><br>
<form id="d1">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Cooperate"> Cooperate
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Betray"> Betray
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
<script>
  function submitAnswer() {
    var selected = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value;
    var myArray = ['Cooperate', 'Betray'];
    var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
    if (selected === "Cooperate" || rand === "Cooperate") {
      alert("2");
    } else if (selected === "Betray" || rand === "Cooperate") {
      alert("3");
    } else if (selected === "Cooperate" || rand === "Betray") {
      alert("0");
    } else if (selected === "Betray" || rand === "Betray") {
      alert("1");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am just starting with javascript to create this game. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: No problem. The console log in the browser is your friend when it comes to detecting syntax errors. Also, a good IDE also helps.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than all the if/thens you could have a single array of possibilities. You could then use binary flags and binary `or` to decide which element to select. `coop` would be either `2` or `0` (in binary `10` or `00` and betray could be either `1` or `0`. Together this would make 4 different possibilities: `00`, `01`, `10`, `11` corresponding to integers 0 through 4.

```js
const responses = [
  "coop - coop",
  "coop - betray",
  "betray - coop",
  "betray - betray"
]

function submitAnswer() {
  var selected = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value;
  var myArray = ['Cooperate', 'Betray'];
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
  // selected or'd with rand = correct array index
  console.log(responses[selected | rand])
}
```

```html
<h1>What is your choice?</h1><br>
<form id="d1">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value=0> Cooperate
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value=2> Betray
</form>
<button onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
```

This would allow you to include a lot of different binary choices without a lot of code.

Comment: This option is very interesting. In fact, I would like to implement something similar, to keep track of the responses and score, per round and overall.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered already, but I'd like to point out that in your if statement, the last two cases will never be reached. I think you meant to use the "&&" operator (or perhaps I'm missing something in this example). Regardless, you could consider changing it to something like this:

```
if ( selected === "Betray" ) {
  if ( rand === "Betray" ) {
    alert( "1" );
    return;
  }
  else if ( rand === "Cooperate" ) {
    alert( "2" );
    return;
  }
}
else if ( selected === "Cooperate" ) {
  if ( rand === "Betray" ) {
    alert( "3" );
    return;
  }
  else if ( rand === "Cooperate" ) {
    alert( "4" );
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, you're right. Good point. In fact I am trying to implement a version of the prisoner's dilemma, so I need to contemplate all the cases. Thanks for your advice.